# Jekyll archive link in another language than english

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid, templating

I have this code to generate my archive links with Jekyll

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <h3>Archives</h3>
    <ul>
        {% for post in site.posts %}
          {% assign thisyear = post.date | date: "%B %Y" %}
          {% assign prevyear = post.previous.date | date: "%B %Y" %}
          {% assign counter = counter | plus: 1 %}
          {% if thisyear != prevyear %}
            <li><a href="/archive/#{{ post.date | date:"%B %Y" | }}">{{ thisyear }} ({{ counter }})</a></li>
            {% assign counter = 0 %}
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see it will render something like "May 2015 (3)". I'm trying to achieve something like "Mai 2015 (3)".

Here is how it's done for a simpler loop :

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <h3>Derniers articles</h3>
    <ul class="posts">
        {% for post in site.posts limit:10 %}
           <li>
               <span>
               {{ post.date | date: '%d' }}
               {% assign m = post.date | date: "%-m" %}
                    {% case m %}
                      {% when '1' %}janvier
                      {% when '2' %}février
                      {% when '3' %}mars
                      {% when '4' %}avril
                      {% when '5' %}mai
                      {% when '6' %}juin
                      {% when '7' %}juillet
                      {% when '8' %}août
                      {% when '9' %}septembre
                      {% when '10' %}octobre
                      {% when '11' %}novembre
                      {% when '12' %}décembre
                    {% endcase %}
                {{ post.date | date: '%Y' }}
                </span> &raquo;
               <a href="{{ BASE_PATH }}{{ post.url }}">
               {{ post.title }}</a>
           </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

This code will render "15 janvier 2015" for instance instead of "15 january 2015".

Up to now I did not manage to merge the two loops to create what I want to achieve. Any idea ?

**EDIT**
Made some progress with that code : 
But there is a big problem, it will only render one month instead of all months.
So for now it renders

```
Mai 2015 (4)
```

instead of

```
Mai 2015 (1)
Juin 2015 (1)
Juillet 2015 (2)
```

```
   <ul>
        {% for post in site.posts %}
          {% assign thisyear = post.date | date: "%Y" %}
          {% assign prevyear = post.previous.date | date: "%Y" %}
          {% assign m = post.date | date: "%-m" %}
          {% assign counter = counter | plus: 1 %}
          {% if thisyear != prevyear %}
            <li><a href="/archive/#{{ post.date | date:"%B %Y" | }}">{% case m %}
                  {% when '1' %}janvier
                  {% when '2' %}février
                  {% when '3' %}Mars
                  {% when '4' %}avril
                  {% when '5' %}mai
                  {% when '6' %}juin
                  {% when '7' %}juillet
                  {% when '8' %}août
                  {% when '9' %}septembre
                  {% when '10' %}octobre
                  {% when '11' %}novembre
                  {% when '12' %}décembre
                {% endcase %}{{ thisyear }}&nbsp;({{ counter }})</a></li>
            {% assign counter = 0 %}
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `{% if thisyear != prevyear %}`, you're grouping by year only.

You need to group by month and year.

You print IF :

- not same month `(thismonth != prevmonth)`
- OR same month but not same year `(thisyear != prevyear and thismonth == prevmonth)`

This works :

```
<ul>
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% assign thisyear = post.date | date: "%Y" %}
  {% assign thismonth = post.date | date: "%-m" %}
  {% assign prevyear = post.previous.date | date: "%Y" %}
  {% assign prevmonth = post.previous.date | date: "%-m" %}
  {% assign counter = counter | plus: 1 %}
  {% if (thismonth != prevmonth) or (thisyear != prevyear and thismonth == prevmonth) %}
    <li><a href="/archive/#{{ post.date | date:"%B %Y" | }}">
    {% case thismonth %}
        [ month in french here ]
    {% endcase %}
    {{ thisyear }}&nbsp;({{ counter }})
    </a></li>
    {% assign counter = 0 %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks will try it by monday